# UISuppressionMode register key does not exist in regedit

Tags: wpf, lync, regedit

I'm now developing Lync WPF Application.I want to create lync with UI Suppression Mode.
So I need to configure the 64-bit version of the Lync client to run in UI Suppression mode.
But my problem is UI Suppression Mode register key does not exist in 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Lync]

How can I resolve this problem?

My OS is Window Server 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the registry. If a key is missing, add it. I've always done it manually. Here's an article I found that describes the manual process:

[How to Modify the Windows Registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/136393/en-us)

If you want information on automating this, go to the MSDN Library and do a search for 'registry functions':

[MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/)